# How do I make an auto popup box for my website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have looked everywhere to get a good popup box that auto pops up when the page loads but had no luck. I want a auto popup box that is centered and has overlay and that auto pops up. I want a popup box like this: http://imgur.com/A0NIPny

Can you tell me the code for it and how to do it?? Sorry I'm kinda new at html and stuff but I know the basics and no I don't wanna use WordPress for this

Comment: Obviously you didn't do any effort, as googling "popup box" shows various pages with various codes.

Comment: u_mulder I've looked on google but it confuses me on how to make some of them and lots of them don't have an auto popup function.

Comment: Opening such an overlay is simply done by a handler you register to the document.ready event. The "popup box" itself is nothing but a div element with a raised z-index and a semi transparent background. What you code inside that div element is up to you.

Comment: I'm new to this and idk how to make one... The tuts are confusingggg. Pls give me a code or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about Bootstrap Modal Plugin?

> The Modal plugin is a dialog box/popup window

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Title </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #myModal {
            width: 500px;
            top: 25%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-top: -25px;
            margin-left: -200px;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
              </br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Output:

[image]

**### Check it out.**

Comment: That didn't work plus I want one that pops up automatically not when you click a button.

Comment: it still didn't work probably cause idk what I'm doing... Can you send me a .zip of it working right?? Cause I did it like this: [http://www.filedropper.com/popupboxtest](http://www.filedropper.com/popupboxtest)

Comment: @JamesCornell : It seems that you have not included the required declarations in your file, see now the complete code in the updated answer.

Comment: can you just please send me a .zip with all the stuff in the right place cause I'm still confused.

Comment: @JamesCornell : Just copy the code that I write it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36527794/4509268) then paste in a editor and save under  **.html** extension and run, it will work for sure as you are connected to the internet so the declared files will be called.

Comment: it works but how to I make the box centered and bigger??

Comment: all I need is it centered like in the middle of the page and the box a little bit bigger.

Comment: @JamesCornell : Try to google your problem, anyway I update my answer by adding some CSS code, Good luck.

Comment: Thank you!! This helped me out a lot

Comment: @JamesCornell : Glad to help you! please mark the answer as accepted as it helps you. **Welcome to stackoverflow**

Comment: idk how to do that :/